# i want get posts' comments and i get undefined variable error

Tags: php, comments

i want to show posts' comments but it give me undefined variable error

//here my controller

```
public function show($id){

    $comments=Comment::where('post_id',$id)->first();

    return view('user',compact('comments'));

}
```

//here my comments table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->string('commentable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//and here is my blade

```
<div class="post-footer-comment-wrapper" >
    <b><p>Şərhlər</p></b>
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
    <div class="comment-form">
        <section class="post-body">
            <p>{{  $comment->description  }}</p> <!--  burda ilisdim -->
        </section>
    </div>
```

******UPDATE *** HERE IS MY ADD COMMENT FORM***

```
    <form method="post"   action="{{route('comments')}}">
                                @csrf
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            <label for="comment">Şərh yaz</label><br>&nbsp;
                            <textarea id="comment " name="comment" rows="3" cols="50">
                            </textarea>

                                <input type="hidden" value="{{$post->id}}" name="id">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Şərh yaz</button>
                            </form>


                            <div class="media-body">
                                <a href="#" class="anchor-username"><h4 class="media-heading"> </h4></a>
                                <a href="#" class="anchor-time"> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: your query is wrong. You are selecting single record and trying to that variable in foreach

Comment: fyi `->first()` returns _one_ entry

Comment: With `Comment::where('post_id',$id)->first();`, you're only getting the first comment, not a collection of comments. So your foreach will be iterating through the properties of that first comment, and `$comment->description` won't exist.

Comment: replace ->first() to ->get()

Comment: Undefined variable: comments (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\user.blade.php)

Comment: i changed first() to get() but i get same error

Comment: @IncredibleHat Looks like Laravel, even though it's not tagged. The up function is the database migration, the show function is the controller, and the blade is the template. The view should be receiving `$comments` from the compact function, but it's not for some reason. Unless the blade template being shown is not in `user.blade.php`

Comment: Ahhhhhh. Laravel. Something I apparently have since wipe my brain of lol. Ok ... I will step out ;-)

Comment: i change code but still i get same error.

Comment: try something like return view('user', ['comments'=>$comments]);

Comment: In your controller method, before `return view...` use `dd($comments);` to dump the comments you get.